# React Native navigation after successfully login

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, navigation

I have a **ReactNative project with Typescript**. In my project, I have used Firebase for authentication. I wanna redirect users after successful login.

**My Login screen structure**

Inside of login screen, I have used another component named login form. The login form takes input from users.

**Now the question is:**

How can I navigate the user to another screen after login? I have used React Native Navigation for navigation. I can access navigation props from the login screen but my login functionalities are implemented at the login form component. I couldn't access the navigation props from the loginForm component.

Answer (score 0):

**I answered myself.**

I have use useNavigation() function inside of loginForm component, and it's working well.